# Close Vote Review Stats

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-close

Yesterday I looked at the [Close Vote Review Stats](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats) and there were **4574 Need Review** with **10 Reviewed Today**. This struck me as a little odd because the previous time I looked (which was fairly recent) I recalled there were over 6000, and now today there are only **4053 Need Review** with **13 Reviewed Today** (at time of writing). I thought perhaps this was observation bias so I checked over the course of an hour yesterday and there was a net *increase* of 30 (furthermore, while writing this there has been an increase of 19) so I concluded that might not be the reason.

My question then is how there are so many fewer **Need Review** today than yesterday when the apparent number reviewed yesterday was so small: what are the other mechanisms by which the **Need Review** number changes? Or is this observation bias?

Comment: When you checked how many were *"Reviewed Today"* yesterday, what time did you do it at?, check again in about...  20hrs, the counters have just reset because it's stupid o'clock in the morning.

Comment: @NickA Thanks for the suggestion, I will check closer to when the counter resets as well

Comment: Close votes also do expire after several days, and the number of open reviews also are affected by questions closed outside of the queue (organically or otherwise, e.g.: [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)).

Comment: @SamuelLiew I did not know that, thanks - I think that would explain the effect I'm seeing (if it is a real effect and not observational bias)

Answer (score 3):

The [SE day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27199/what-is-an-se-day-when-does-each-day-start) resets at 00:00UTC, approximately 2hrs ago.

Since you asked this question the number reviewed today has gone up from 13 to 34, you should try checking the counter *before* the end of the day (approximately 21hrs45min from time of writing).

You're just checking the counters at the wrong time of day. You'll find that the number reviewed will increase *dramatically*.

---

The number reviewed today <sub>obviously</sub> goes up whenever a review is performed today (individual reviews, not a result of a post leaving the queue, i.e. the number of reviews today can go up by more than one without affecting the number of reviews in the queue).

The number needing reviewed can go up by flags (close flags), or close votes.

The number needing reviewed can go down by reviews being performed and a question either being closed or leaving the queue (as a result of enough leave open reviews being performed, or by the close votes aging away).

Comment: The number reviewed has gone up, but there has still been a net increase of 16 to the number needing review, and the same was the case during the time I observed yesterday - a net increase of 30 needing reviewed.... still, I will assume this is observational bias until I check the numbers at the end of day as you suggest. Thank you